# Send file to WhatsApp API's '/media' endpoint present in S3 bucket without storing it locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, whatsapp

**TL;DR:**
I  want to send a file that is in an S3 bucket to WhatsApp API's /media endpoint without saving it locally first.

**Long Version:**
I'm trying to store file in WhatsApp server by sending request to /media endpoint in WhatsApp cloud API. I'm getting a success response when file is present locally by using fs.createReadStream('file-path'), but failing when I get file from S3 and create a read stream.

In terms of code:

```
const stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: this.bucketName, Key: fileNameWithFullPath }).createReadStream()
```

Then I add header, and other required parameters and send the request.

```
const formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", stream, { contentType: "application/pdf" });
formdata.append("messaging_product", "whatsapp");
try {
  const {
  data: { id: mediaId },
  } = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/${this.graphAPIVersion}/${this.senderPhoneNumberId}/media`, formdata, {
  headers: {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
  ...formdata.getHeaders(),
  }
});
  console.log("Success: ", mediaId);
}
catch (error) {
  console.error("Error: ", error)
}
```

The error has status code 500 with no specific cause.

```
error: {
  statusCode: 500,
  statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
  message: 'An unknown error has occurred.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 1,
  fbtrace_id: 'AxiCaSoItKscIF1qVgy3bej'
}
```

I'm pretty sure that nothing else is wrong with this request because when I replace S3's createReadStream() with fs.createReadStream('file-path'), it is working fine.

Please keep in mind that there is no local file storage available in the server from where this function will be called. That's why I won't be able to store the file locally first before sending request to WhatsApp API's /media endpoint.

Comment: Are you using native `FormData` or the one from the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) package?

Comment: Which AWS SDK version are you using?

Comment: I'm using form-data package, and aws-sdk: "^2.1171.0",

Comment: I'd start by debugging the S3 object stream. Can you write it to a local file (testing locally)? You might also want to update to the v3 SDK as finding examples, issues and documentation is certainly a lot easier

Comment: Yeah, I logged read stream of both fs and S3, they are different, should I paste both of them here for reference? And I will try using v3 SDK and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I think your concern is whether I'm able to receive object from S3, if that's the case then yes I checked by downloading the file before creating read stream.

Comment: Downloading it via the Node SDK using whatever credentials your app is using?

Comment: Yes, to save the file locally, I created an S3 read stream, and used fs.createWriteStream() to write the file into local storage.

Comment: Without more info from the Whatsapp API, your next best try would be to test it yourself. Create your own upload service (eg Express + Multer) or use an _echo_ service like https://echo.zuplo.io/ and send the request to it so you can debug any problems. I'd start with a very small PDF too for simplicity